# Wordpress Plugin for Google Maps: How to return the Map

Tags: wordpress, function

I have a PHP Site which takes Data from XML File to display Markers on a Google Maps. When I navigate direct to the page, everything is working. To integrate that code on my Wordpress Page, I thought about writing a plugin for that:

```
<? defined('ABSPATH') or die("Thanks for visting"); 

function showMap() { ?>

 <style>
  /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
   * element that contains the map. */
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
  /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
</style>

<div id="map"></div>

<script>
  var customLabel = {
    Location: {
      label: 'L'
    },
    Brautaustatter: {
      label: 'B'
    },
    Herrenausstatter: {
      label: 'H'
    },
    Florist: {
      label: 'F'
    },
    Konditor: {
      label: 'K'
    },
    Sonstiges: {
      label: 'S'
    }
  };

 function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.2048, 16.375),
      zoom: 12
    });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
      downloadUrl('showXML.php', function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
          var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
          var name = markerElem.getAttribute('location');
          var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
          var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

          var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
          var strong = document.createElement('strong');
          strong.textContent = name
          infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
          infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

          var text = document.createElement('text');
          text.textContent = address
          infowincontent.appendChild(text);
          var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            label: icon.label
          });
          marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
        });
      });


    }



  function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState == 4) {
        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
        callback(request, request.status);
      }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
  }



function doNothing() {}
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&callback=initMap">
</script>

<? add_shortcode( 'show_google_maps', 'showMap' ); ?>
<? } ?>
```

Now I do not know how to return the whole map with the markers? How can I solve this? Do I have to create a "main" function where all the other functions are nested? Is that what I want to achieve possible with that piece of code? Thanks for any advice!

BR,

Stefan

Comment: Do you need it embedded into a page/post or would it be a page dedicated to that map? You can could create a custom page/post template if its a dedicated page. You could create a simple shortcode to embed it on to a wordpress page. Looks like you have thought of that. A shortcode would be a simple solution. I guess I need a little more information on what youre trying to do.

Comment: Hi Dan, thank you for feedback. I thought about a shortcode to show it on a page or post. But I do not know how I can call the function. During my research I have seen that most of the plugins are "return" the expected value. I know how to return a string, but how do I return a whole function? Like in my example, how do I return the function showMap()?

Comment: All of your code is javascript. I would create an external javascript file and enqueue that. [see](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/). You could then just write a shortcode function to output the div with the ID map on to the appropriate page. Or, you could just put the html for the div with the ID map on the page manually.

Comment: Thank you Dan - I will do that! BR, Stefan